# Re-enter try statement after an except

Tags: python, exception, try-except

In my code below, it stops executing when I hit an exception.  How can I get it to re-enter the `try` statement from where the exception left off?  Maybe I am looking for a different way to tackle this without a try-except statement?

```
import requests
from requests import exceptions

contains_analyst = []

try:
    for x in data:
        r = requests.get(str(x), timeout=10, verify=False)

        if "analyst" in r.text:
            contains_analyst.append("Analyst")
            print "Analyst @ %s" % x
        else:
            contains_analyst.append("NOPERS")
            print "Nopers"

except exceptions.RequestException:
    contains_analyst.append("COULD NOT CONNECT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the try/except around *only* the part whose error you want to trap.  In your example, it looks like you want something more like this:

```
for x in data:
    try:
        r = requests.get(str(x), timeout=10, verify=False)
    except exceptions.RequestException:
        contains_analyst.append("COULD NOT CONNECT") 
    else:
        if "analyst" in r.text:
            contains_analyst.append("Analyst")
            print "Analyst @ %s" % x
        else:
            contains_analyst.append("NOPERS")
            print "Nopers"
```

Here I use the `else` clause of the `try` block to handle the case where no exception is raised (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)).  In many cases, if you don't need to do anything else after the exception, you could just return at that point and put the following no-exception code in the main function body, reducing indentation a bit:

```
for x in data:
    try:
        r = requests.get(str(x), timeout=10, verify=False)
    except exceptions.RequestException:
        contains_analyst.append("COULD NOT CONNECT")
        return contains_analyst

    # execution reaches here if no exception
    if "analyst" in r.text:
        contains_analyst.append("Analyst")
        print "Analyst @ %s" % x
    else:
        contains_analyst.append("NOPERS")
        print "Nopers"
```

Of course, whether it makes sense to return at that point depends on the surrounding context of your code.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  I don't know why I thought I had to keep the whole try statement as it was...thanks